# ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (13, 64)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have made a model and have got this error (it is a kaggle notebook), this is the error:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (13, 64)

        <ipython-input-25-f223adf5c5a7> in <module>
             12   for i in range(len(scores_transformed_train)):
             13     # Optimize the model
        ---> 14     loss_value, grads = grad(temp_model, title_train[i], 
    scores_transformed_train[i])
             15     optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, temp_model.trainable_variables))
             16
```

The model:

```
    encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization()

    encoder.adapt(title_train)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        encoder,
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
            output_dim=64,
            mask_zero=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')
    ])
```

my functions

```
    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    
    def loss(model, x, y, training):
      y_ = model(x, training=training)

      return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)


    def grad(model, inputs, targets):
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=True)
      return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
```

Please help me fix it. I will be happy to answer any additional queries if needed...

Answer (score 1):

Usually the expected dimension in such model is 3.
(time x batch x features). You provided a 2d.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Reshape layer after Bidirectional layer

Some thing like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 1), input_shape = (128, )),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
```